# In R does the fromLast argument in duplicated() work on integer64 vectors?

Tags: r

I'm trying to identify duplicates in an integer64 vector using the `fromLast` argument in the `duplicated()` function (my rows are ordered in time and I want to discard the earlier time points, keeping the most recent unique value). It doesn't seem to work.

It works for regular integer vectors:

```
> x <- c(1, 2, 3, 3, 4)

> base::duplicated(x)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE

> base::duplicated(x, fromLast = TRUE)
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

This is the correct behavior.

But it doesn't work on an integer64 vector:

```
> x <- as.integer64(c(1, 2, 3, 3, 4))

> base::duplicated(x)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE

> base::duplicated(x, fromLast = TRUE)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Any ideas?

The `duplicated.integer64()` function doesn't have a `fromLast` argument.

I can do `rev(duplicated(rev(x)))`, but according to base R's documentation this is slower than using `fromLast=TRUE`.

Comment: Are you talking about the `bit64` package?

Comment: Yes, I should have made that more clear. Looks like (based on accepted answer below) in my code I was still unknowingly calling the `duplicated()` function from the `bit64` package.

Comment: ok - well yes, if you call `duplicated`, it *will* call `duplicated`, but `duplicated` will dispatch to whatever appropriate method is registered (through `UseMethod("duplicated")`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the method dispatched.  It is calling the `duplicated.integer64`.   If we want the same behaviour, use `duplicated.default`

```
duplicated.default(x, fromLast = TRUE)
#[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

By checking the `duplicated.integer64`, it doesn't have the `fromLast` argument

```
> duplicated.integer64
function (x, incomparables = FALSE, nunique = NULL, method = NULL, 
...)
```

where as there is an argument for `fromLast` in `duplicated.default`

```
> duplicated.default
 function (x, incomparables = FALSE, fromLast = FALSE, nmax = NA, 
  ...)
```

#### data

```
library(bit64)
x <- as.integer64(c(1, 2, 3, 3, 4))
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that even if I pre-pended the function with `base::` that it would still call the version of `duplicate` from the `bit64` package.